# Routing in the most SEO friendly way with Angular?

Tags: seo, javascript, navigation, angular

Currently I have an Angular app that routes to a to the "Home` location when the user clicks the logo like this:

```
  home() {
    this.router.navigate([''])
  }
```

Is there a more SEO friendly / best practice way to do this?

Comment: Are you wrapping the logo in a link to the home page when it renders?

Comment: I will now :) - Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I've never used Angular so I'm not sure how it works by default.  Does your code end up changing the URL using `pushState`?

Comment: Yes I believe that's how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more SEO friendly way. Instead of calling function that will do redirect, you can do it directly in HTML.

```html
<a [routerLink]="'/'">Home</a>
```